# Merging two different table's data by SQL

Tags: sql, database, merge

I have a two different tables, **Country_m** and **State_m**

the `State` Table has fields like `StateId, Name, CountryId, etc`, and `Country` Table has fileds like `CountryId, Name, Currency, etc`.

I want to get a datagrid of State Table in which it should print State Name and respective Country Name... how to execute this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select t1.Name state_name, t2.Name Country_name from State_m t1,Country_m t2 where t1.CountryId=t2.CountryId;
```

use thsi

Comment: this was simplest ... thnx :)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT S.NAME as STATE_NAME,C.NAME COUNTRY_NAME
FROM STATE_M S JOIN COUNTRY_M C
ON S.COUNTRYID=C.COUNTRYID;
```

Comment: @azzy is this is what you want?

Comment: yupp... but what the names of the Name fileds are just Name in state table and country table

Comment: using 'join' keyword is ANSI format @azzy. So that whenver you go for migration to any database this format will work anywhere without any change. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
 select s.name as STATENAME,c.name AS COUNTRYNAME from state s 
 inner join country c 
 on s.countryid=c.countryid
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a join.  It might be a good idea to learn about them first:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: @full.stack LAL give answer not links

Comment: @Azzy Please don't use chatspeak. It is frowned upon here on SO.

Comment: @ Manish Nagar: that's the answer in this case.  A piece of key information about SQL joins for the asker, who seemed to need just that.  It's much better to get a systemic view than a clip of code you don't understand in-depth.